# Should PHP frameworks generate JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, frameworks

I've noticed that a PHP frameworks; [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html), [Cake](http://book.cakephp.org/view/349/Methods), and [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_2/symfony-ajax); seem to either generate JavaScript or allow it to be embedded as a string into the PHP itself. Is this a good idea? From people who've used these frameworks/libraries, what has been your experience working with the Ajax and JavaScript helpers? Has it been easy to maintain? Does it cut down on development time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No it is a bad idea,

Generated javascript usually means that the site won't even function without it (like many asp.net sites). If you want to do more complex things or want to enhance accesibility there is no other way around than clearly seperating HTML from CSS and Javascript.

Seperating Javascript also makes your code more maintainable as you do not need to have your client side frontend developers mess with your PHP code and the other way around.

The best way to use Javascript is to first let php generate your html, then at the bottom of that page include your javascript files and use functionality like onDomReady. This also doesn't force you to use a particular library just because your framework is using that as base for its generated Javascript.

Comment: I agree if the site relies on the javascript but there's no problem generating js if it is separate from the HTML. It can be handy if you want to generate variables specific to the current user such as preferences.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a subjective question, but personally, I wouldn't want a back-end framework to do this for me. It's better to keep a clean seperation between business logic, presentation, and client-side UI behaviours for a number of reasons:

- More maintainable applications.
- Easier to test individual components.
- Easier collaboration. Different skill-sets can work on different areas.
- Should help ensure your application does not rely on JavaScript in the end users environment.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like to write my Javascript by hand, unobtrusively so that i just have to add an extra event to document.domReady with for example the correct parameters. That little trigger function then gets the ball rolling.

Best practice of the day:

> Keep frontend-code and backend code
>   untangled as much as you can

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends, like anything. There is certainly some value in having "smart" server side widgets. For example, a widget that "knows" how to update itself through AJAX, or a form which can handle client side, and server side validation. The latter is an example of which it would be costly and time consuming and error prone to rewrite boring validation code in the client. It doesn't require rocket-science javascript, so as long as your framework can handle it unobtrusively, I would actually *advise* this route. 
Additionally, framework code that will handle GUI stuff also (a la ext or something similar), is also not a bad a idea.

However, anything more complicated than that, please use Javascript itself.

Answer (score 1):

I personally love writing my own Javascript so I don't really want it written for me, but I don't see it as being particularly 'dangerous' or 'harmful' to have frameworks that do it for you, as long as it is properly done. My biggest problem with them is that most of them will work as long as you want the standard behavior of a feature, but as soon as you want something a little different to meet your project's needs better it takes so much work to customize it you would have been better served to do it yourself. At least that was my experience with CakePHP's javascript automation.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with the Javascript and Ajax helpers in CakePHP has been very positive.

They have allowed server-side developers to prototype and build features that otherwise would require someone with real client-side experience to do, all without having worry about the quality of the javascript code they *"write"* and leaving the real front-end engineers free to focus on the advanced client-side features.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea for the PHP to generate Javascript. The only javascript I would recommend exporting is simple JSON assignments like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  var MyNamespace.info = <?php echo json_encode($info_array) ?>
// --></script>
```

This is the easiest way to sanitize PHP information and let it be accessible to javascript on the client. However, anything else should be written in actual JAVASCRIPT FILES that are referenced with  tags at the head of the document. The only other appearance of Javascript from server-side files, that I would say is alright, is stuff placed into "onclick" and other such attributes.

The rationale for this is that the Javascript should be written and maintained by front-end people who know Javascript, and the site should be able to work (at least partially) without javascript. There is no reason to generate spaghetti Javascript inline.

Check out my PHP framework, PHP On Pie (http://phponpie.com) for an example of how to implement this properly. It keeps the JS and PHP separate, except when exporting JSON as shown above. However it also provides conventions for easy interoperation between the client and server via AJAX.

Comment: I agree.  Just a note that jQuery makes it easy to add the various event handlers purely on the javascript side, which I find has a much nicer format than the PHP-way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should keep languages apart. Even though they can complement each other. That way you can pick the implementation of said language and create a mix that fits you perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is definitely a place for generated javascript. (1)

The number one reason for generated javascript is ease of maintenance. Any dependencies are explicitly encoded and configured from the framework (PHP, ruby, scala, python) itself. For instance if you move your assets or change the upload directory, just update the configuration and watch things Just Work.

Need client side input validation to take some load off your server? (2) Let the framework generate correct validation code derived directly from your data model for you. With generated, javascripted population your framework can serve pre-rendered, static HTML forms from the cache. This could be a huge win if your forms contain lots of selects and options.

1) Assuming that the client has decided that it's OK for the site to depend (more or less) on javascript, with all the caveats that entails. Graceful degradation may or may not be possible or desirable.

2) You need server side side validation too, but you knew that, right?