# Rewrite the code to handle the views in an Angular-Laravel App

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am working on an App which is going to be huge.This app is using Laravel for backend and currently uses Angular to load views which i believe is not suitable for a large application.I would like to rewrite the code to load the views using Laravel's Blade engine.

I have gone through this:
[What application structure to use with AngularJS and Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18420434/5475205)

I am interested in the second option provided in the answer but have no idea how to implement it in my existing application.

Please suggest me what changes do i need to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't you read all of it? It's pretty useless. Either use them correctly or don't use them at all. There are 0 benefits to combining them this way. Keep your current project as is or ditch AngularJS. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I am digging my way to route all the views using laravel and use Angular to interact with the DOM elements.I don't see any need to ditch Angular.